# C pointer to another variable

Tags: c, pointers

I'm trying to make an alias (`firstElementNum`) to an array element for the sake of abstracting complexity away from the programmer. Here's my code:

```
typedef struct {
    int structNum;
} myStruct;

myStruct myArray[10];

int *const firstElementNum = myArray[0].structNum;
```

When I tried this, I got `initializer element is not a constant`. I guess that means the right hand side needs to be a defined constant. So how am I supposed to assign this pointer to my target element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *const firstElementNum = &myArray[0].structNum;
```

Note the "address of" operator, `&`, since you want `firstElementNum` to point to the address of `myArray[0].structNum`.

Comment: Excellent. But to assign it, `firstElementNum = 5` for example complains that I'm trying to write to a read-only variable - which signifies it's trying to overwrite the pointer. It stopped complaining if I did `*firstElementNum`, so do I have to dereference my alias every time I read to or write from it?

Comment: @CJxD yes, that's correct. A pointer is not strictly an alias.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like from your questions that you are unclear on the fundamental rules for pointers. Many people who post questions in the C tag are unclear on this.  Basically:

- A *storage location* can hold a *value* of a particular *type*.
- If you apply the `&` operator to a *storage location* you get a *pointer* to the associated *type*.
- A *pointer* is a *value*.
- If you apply the `*` operator to a *pointer* you get a *storage location*.

Technically a storage location is called an "lvalue" but that seems needlessly jargonish for the beginner.

So let's take a look:

```
int *const firstElementNum = myArray[0].structNum;
```

That's not right. `structNum` is a storage location that contains a value of type `int`. But to assign to `firstElementNum` we want an expression of type "pointer to `int`".

Try again:

```
int *const firstElementNum = &myArray[0].structNum;
```

That's better. `structNum` is a *storage location* of type `int`. The `&` operator gives you a pointer to `int`. That's a *value* that can be stored in storage location `firstElementNum`.

```
firstElementNum = 5;
```

This is doubly wrong; first, you're trying to write to a `const` storage location, and second, this is trying to assign a value of type `int` to a storage location of type "pointer to `int`".

```
*firstElementNum = 5;
```

This is right. `firstElementNum` is a storage location that contains a pointer to `int`. Applying `*` to that value makes a storage location of type `int`, which is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what `int *const` is: read it from backwards ie. `constant pointer to an integer`.

so you must assign it to a pointer, not an integer

```
int *const firstElementNum = &myArray[0].structNum;
```

Now, you can access the value using the deference operator: `* firstElementNum`.